# This JavaScript program document.write () is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning how to use JavaScript and I am having trouble correctly displaying the url within the document.write() function. I am writing the program with an actual url in the "href" portion but I can not write it in this question since it is apparently prohibited to do so. Is there something that I am missing?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Link Test </title>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="mylink" href="#"> Click me</a>
    <br>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        url = document.links.mylink.href document.write('The URL is ' + url)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon if you want to have it on one line. Like this:

```
url = document.links.mylink.href; document.write('The URL is ' + url);
```

I would however recommend putting them on two lines, like this:

```
var url = document.links.mylink.href; 
document.write('The URL is ' + url);
```

..and using `var` to declare url as a variable, good practice

Comment: As of ES2015, `let` or `const` are recommended over `var`.

Comment: Absolutely, just afraid if you start looking at ES2015 features directly when new to javascript, you might run into stuff that might not be supported in your browser, if you are new to the whole javascript scene. But you got my upvote! :)

Comment: If you're just learning JavaScript for the first time, I don't think you care very much about browsers 10 years old. Also, there are tools for that. In short: I don't care, and I think that neither should you.

Comment: We are not really talking about you and me right, but an answer to a person that is totally new to javascript. Isn't it good to try to avoid as many pitfalls you can run into as possible in the beginning? I personally would not use ES2015 directly ( check mobile: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ ) without using something like babel. And babel etc, imho, is to early to introduce to someone totally new to javascript.

Comment: That's fair. +1 regardless :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `type="text/JavaScript"` part from your code. Some modern browsers will give you an error on it.

Also I suggest you to write your statements in separate lines. JS engine understands your whole line as a one statement. So it gives an error. I suggest you to separate lines and put `;` at the end of each line or you can add `;` after the statement, if you want to write in one line. And also define your variables with `var` or `let` and `const` in ES6.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Link Test </title>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="mylink" href="#"> Click me</a>
    <br>
    <script>
        var url = document.links.mylink.href ;
        document.write('The URL is ' + url);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He doesn't have to write them in separate lines, he can either add semicolons, separate the lines, or both. Both is the recommended course of action in most cases.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha has been changed

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = document.links.mylink.href;
document.write('The URL is ' + link);
```

But still, I won't recommend using `document.write` method. You'd better add some html tag, where you can safely insert the result via `innerHtml` or `innerText` methods:

**html:**

```
<a id="mylink" href="#Test"> Click me</a>
<span id="result"></span>
```

**js:**

```
let url = document.links.mylink.href;
let result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerText = url;
```